# not able to make http-client call from spring xd with rabbit transport

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-xd

I have created a stream like below and using rabbit as transport

```
xd:>stream create --name test6 --definition "http | http-client --url='''http://localhost:8080/mock-sentmessage/customers/send-email''' --httpMethod=POST | log " --deploy
```

Now I am  getting below exception  when i try to post this

```
http post --contentType 'application/json'--data '{"profileReferenceID":"test","templateURL":{"type":"type","href":"","method":"POST"}}'
```

I am  able to make a request from my POSTMAN client but fails from spring-xd

Log

```
 2015-11-13T13:25:42-0600 1.2.1.RELEASE WARN xdbus.test9.0-1 retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer - Retries exhausted for message (Body:'{"profileReferenceID":"xxx","templateURL":{"type":"type","href":"yyy","method":"POST"}}'MessageProperties [headers={requestMethod=POST, User-Agent=Java/1.8.0_60, Host=localhost:9000, Content-Length=305, contentType=text/plain, requestPath=/, originalContentType=application/json;charset=UTF-8}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, expiration=null, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.test9.0, deliveryTag=19, messageCount=0])
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:864) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:759) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:170) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:74) ~[spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:263) [spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:168) [spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:98) [spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.invokeListener(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1257) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:660) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1021) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1005) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1119) [spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://10.219.7.75:8080/mock-sentmessage/customers/send-email]; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:410) ~[spring-integration-http-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:287) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:245) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:287) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:245) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:101) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$400(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:45) ~[spring-integration-amqp-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$1.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:93) ~[spring-integration-amqp-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:756) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:614) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:570) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:545) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:466) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:383) ~[spring-integration-http-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

> 400 Bad Request

That's a response from the server - it doesn't like the data you sent.

I suggest you compare the requests from POSTMAN and XD using wireshark or similar, to see what's different.

Comment: Thansk for that Now  I tried this  stream create --name test18 --definition "http --outputType='application/json' | http-client --outputType='application/json' --inputType='application/json'  --url='''http://10.219.16.231:8080/SampleServices/rest/hello/post''' --httpMethod=POST | log " --deploy   when i post data  I face   Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://10.219.16.231:8080/SampleServices/rest/hello/post]; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: I have set the output and input type in my stream

Comment: Again; take a look at the network trace to see what's different. Please don't put code/config in comments here; it's virtually unreadable; edit the question instead,